# FB.getLoginStatus not running in a $.ready

Tags: html, fbml, facebook-opengraph, facebook-java-sdk

I need to run the fb inside a $.ready to do some checkings.
The alert in getLoginStatus function never trigger ?!

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if(Setting_ShowLike){
            FB.init({
                appId   : 'APP_ID',
                status  : true,
                cookie  : true,
                xfbml   : true,
                oauth   : true,
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
                alert('callback');
            });
        }


    });
    </script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div class="fb-like" href="http://www.facebook.com/windows" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Comment: Make sure that `Setting_ShowLike` is resolved and inner code is executed.

Comment: Setting_ShowLike is resolved of course and = true;

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `<div id="fb-root"></div>` all the way up, right before `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>`.

It should work fine after that.